# Bootstrap4 columns containing absolutely positioned elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been working on a game and, for certain things, I used absolute positioning. In particular, I need it for some moving animations where I have to slide elements around and overlap them to create an effect.

I'm trying to work on making the game good-looking on mobile, and I've been running into some problems caused by Bootstrap `col`umns that contain those absolutely positioned elements.

This is the look I'm trying to get (aside from the badly aligned number), notice the red squared row in the middle:

[image]

The whole center part of the screen (the row with buttons, emojis, and the centered card icon underneath) is a `row` containing `col`s. This is some of its markup

```
<div class="col order-1 order-xl-1 col-4 col-xl-2">
    <div style="display:inline-block">
        <p class="backgrounded-text" style="white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis;"><span id="turn_elem">...</span></span></p>
        <p class="backgrounded-text">Carta attuale: <span id="curr_card"><img class="card_icon" /></span></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="reaction_box order-2 order-xl-2 col col-4 col-xl-2">
    <span style="padding-left:5px!important;padding-right:5px!important" class="reaction_title">Reazioni:</span>
    <table>
        <!-- emojis ... -->
    </table> 
</div>
<div class="col order-5 order-xl-3 col-12 col-xl-3">
    <span>...</span><br />
    <span id="hidden_card">
        <img class="card_placeholder" src="..." />
    </span>
    <span id="card_stack" class="slide_to_right">
        <img class="card_placeholder" src="..." />
    </span>
    <div id="stacked_card"> 
      <img id="stacked_front" class="card_placeholder" src="..." />
    </div>
    <div id="hidden_uncovered_card_div">
        <img id="hidden_uncovered_card" class="card_placeholder" src="..." />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col col-4 order-3 order-xl-4 col-xl-3">
        <button style="width: 49%" class="btn btn-lg btn-dark" id="doubt" @click="doubt()" :disabled="playing_animation">Dubito!</button>
        <button style="width: 49%" class="btn btn-lg btn-dark">
            Metti giù
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `img` that has id `hidden_card` is a card to the left of the red one that is made visible and slides to the right to cover that (it uses jQuery `animate` to manipulate the position). On top of `stacked_card`, which is the main red card that's displayed in the screenshots, there's another copy of it, that is flipped with jQuery and moved to the right to overlap `hidden_uncovered_card`. This is pretty much how the animations work. They all depend on using `position: absolute` and manipulating the positioning.

For some reason, the actual look I'm getting with the above code is this:

[image]

There is some space in between the three columns on the top and the one containing the red card back, and I don't understand where it is coming from.
Removing all the `position: absolute` seems to fix this, but of course, then all the animations that depend on it stop working.

Is there any way to fix this positioning without removing the `position: absolute`? It'd be a pain to have to rewrite the code for all the animations, as it's working perfectly on desktop.

Here's a static webpage that contains the markup. You can turn it to mobile view (the screenshots were taken as iPhone 6/7/8 mode) and see for yourself.

[click](https://samul-1.github.io/test1/127.0.0.1.html)

The actual app (a beta version, that is) can be found [here](http://dubito.herokuapp.com/game), in case you wanted to see how the animations work. If you need any additional information, just let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap is using a 12 colums grid.

Check how you use them.

You have:

```
<div class="col order-1 order-xl-1 col-4 col-xl-2">The two button on the left<div>
<div class="reaction_box order-2 order-xl-2 col col-4 col-xl-2">the emojis</div>
<div class="col order-5 order-xl-3 col-12 col-xl-3">the red cards</div>
<div class="col col-4 order-3 order-xl-4 col-xl-3">the three button on the right</div>
```

You should clean that!!!

Example:

- `col` followed by `col-4` is the same as just `col-4` where `col-4` overrides `col`.
- `order-1` and `order-xl-1` is redondant if there is no `order-md-3` (for example)
  Just `order-1` is enought here.

For these 4 divs, make sure you use the 12 grid spaces correctly.

So about the `col` and `col-*` usage, for mobile size, you actually have 24 spaces used out of 12.

1. 4 spaces
2. 4 spaces
3. 12 spaces
4. 4 spaces

And whent the `col-xl-*` applies, you have 10 spaces used out of 12. *Is that on purpose?*

1. 2 spaces
2. 2 spaces
3. 3 spaces
4. 3 spaces

---

So here is what I suggest for a start:

```
<div class="col-3 col-xl-2 order-1">The two button on the left<div>
<div class="reaction_box col-4 col-xl-2 order-2">the emojis</div>
<div class="col-2 col-xl-3 order-3">the red cards</div>
<div class="col-3 order-4">the three button on the right</div>
```

which doesn't change the xl size at all, but produces this (iphone 6/7/8 mode):

[image]

That's a start.

So the trick is to have the classe in order... All the `col-*` from default to the bigger specific size... And then the `order-*` in order too. That make the markup readable.

;)

---

**EDIT**

To have the red cards looking like *on another row* :

```
<div class="col-4 col-xl-2 order-1">The two button on the left<div>
<div class="reaction_box col-4 col-xl-2 order-2">the emojis</div>
<div class="col-10 col-xl-3 order-4 order-xl-3 sm-translateUp">the red cards</div>
<div class="col-4 order-3 order-xl-4">the three button on the right</div>
```

Notice the order changed and that there is an additional `.sm-translateUp` class which would be:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 576px){
  .sm-translateUp{
     transform: translateY(-85px);
  }
}
```

That makes:

[image]

Now that really looks like a hack... (LOL) But since that `col` is trapped inside its parent `.row`, that is all I think of for the moment.

So have that class defined inside all necessary @media rules for each bootstrap break points:

- sm: >= 576px
- md: >= 768px
- lg: >= 992px
- xl: >= 1200px

Comment: Thank you. The mobile version is indeed intended to use 24 spaces. What I'm trying to do is have the col containing the red cards on a different row, but only on mobile. However, as you can see, while I do get it on a second line, it's way down far away from the others. The reason it needs a whole line is this video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BYJFFMpODhHu8l-Eh3sQcCeuh4aEocWo/view?usp=drivesdk literally in the first 5 seconds you'll see the animations I'm talking about and whey they need some width dedicated to them alone

Comment: More specifically, the first animation is within the first five seconds, and the second is at timestamp 0:47. Now you'll have a clear picture of my issue for sure. I failed to make it clear in my initial post

Comment: Thank you once again, I'll give it a go and see how it looks on various screen sizes.